# Wifi enabled printer configuration

Tags: printing, configuration

I have a wifi capable printer and a desktop computer. I currently use the Ethernet connection to my router for printing from the computer but I also wish to be able to print from my iPad/iPhone to the same printer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

first I would like to say that this isn't a question related to a problem with linux. Linux will not block other programs from using your printer so if you can configure your ipad to accept the printer you'll have no problem printing.

now to solve your problem.

If you have a HP printer try installing eprint on your ipad/iphone. 
You could also try airprint to print using your wifi printer.

If that doesn't work google your printer manufacturer with the keywords "ipad" or "iphone". It should become clear really fast if it's possible or not with your printer.